# Listing cities in an itinerary

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record

I have a has_many through relationship between my cities and travels that looks like this:

```
class Travel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities, through: :destinations
end
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :travels, through: :destinations
end
```

And on my `Travel` controller I have a method to join all its `cities` names:

```
  def city_names
    self.cities.map { |e| e.name }.join(', ')
  end
```

I installed the bullet gem and it tells me that this is a n+1 query and suggests that I add the `includes` method on the query, but as far as I can tell this method will only work if I call it directly on the `Travel` class.

Comment: Don't use the meaningless variable `e`; use something like `city` instead

Comment: Did you try calling `includes` on `self` in the `city_names` method?

Comment: even better, just call map with `(&:name)` instead of a block

Answer (score 2):

You can use `includes` on any activerecord relation.

Judging by your message about having `N+1` queries I suspect you are calling `city_names` somewhere in a loop. then the correct placement of the `includes` is the place where you select the elements to loop past.

I'm guessing it is for a view or something so i write some example code for `.html.erb`.

In controller:

```
@travels = Travels.all.includes(destinations: :cities)
```

In view:

```
<% @travels.each do |travel| %>
  ... Some code displaying travel info
  <%= travel.city_names %>
  ... More code displaying travel info
<% end %>
```

And a suggestion in line with what Mark Thomas wrote as a comment. You can refactor you `city_names` method for more readable code, either according to his suggestion or like this:

```
def city_names
  self.cities.map(&:name).join(', ')
end
```